# Return 1 Row based on Two Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a pricelist as per the following table. I want to return a table made of distinct ItemCode values based on the following conditions, related each other...

- If USD = true THEN return the row with USD price else EUR price
- If EndDate IS NULL then return the row with NULL EndDate else the row w/ NOT NULL EndDate

```
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| ItemCode  | Price | Currency | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| A02143803 | 18    | USD      | 01/09/2019 | NULL       |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| A02143803 | 17    | EUR      | 01/09/2019 | NULL       |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| A02143805 | 18    | USD      | 01/09/2019 | 31/12/2019 |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| A02143805 | 17,7  | USD      | 01/01/2020 | NULL       |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
| A02143805 | 16    | EUR      | 01/09/2019 | NULL       |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+
```

The End Result should be like:

```
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| ItemCode  | Price | Currency | StartDate  | EndDate |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| A02143803 | 18    | USD      | 01/09/2019 | NULL    |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| A02143805 | 17,7  | USD      | 01/01/2020 | NULL    |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Please can you suggest what would be the best way to get this result?
Would `COALESCE` be able to solve my problem?

Comment: What does "if USD is true" mean? Are you passing some kind of parameter which will have a value of `'USD'` or `NULL`?

Comment: What is there is a row with `currency=EUR` and no end date and a row with `currency=USD` and an end date? Does the currency take precedence?

Comment: Do you have different columns with the prices in USD and EUR?

Comment: @G.Langlois -> Yes

Comment: @DStanley -> USD currency take precedence

Comment: @Lamu -> No parameters are passed, i though it was easier to understand... maybe not true

Comment: @PeterSmith No homework assignment, real scenario. I used GROUP BY and CASE with no success ... :-)

Comment: Great; glad you get your solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with prioritized sequence  :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by itemcode 
                                order by (case when Currency = 'USD' then 0 else 1 end),
                                         (case when enddate is null then 0 else 1 end), enddate
                               ) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```